# Write input text in ul on keyup

Tags: javascript

I have made a small todo list in order to get better at javascript. It adds a new todo and deletes it. It also has a counter. I want to make possible to add a new todo not only by clicking the button but by also pressing the enter key. How can that happen? Here is my code:

```
 var button = document.getElementById('add-button');
        var count = 0;

        button.addEventListener('click', function () {    
        var item = document.getElementById('input').value;
        var text = document.createTextNode(item);
        var newItem = document.createElement('li');
        newItem.appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);
        count++;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;


        var removeTask = document.createElement('img');
        removeTask.setAttribute('src', './images/trash.jpg');
        removeTask.setAttribute('id', 'trash');
        removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
            newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
            count--;
            document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
        });
        newItem.appendChild(removeTask);

    });
```

And here is my attempt that did not work:

```
    var button = document.getElementById('add-button');
    var count = 0;
    var input = document.getElementById('input');

   input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {    
    event.preventDefault(); 
    if (key === 13) { 
    var item = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(item);
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.appendChild(text);
    document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);
    count++;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
    }
    var removeTask = document.createElement('img');
    removeTask.setAttribute('src', './images/trash.jpg');
    removeTask.setAttribute('id', 'trash');
    removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
        newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
        count--;
        document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
    });
    newItem.appendChild(removeTask);

});
```

and here is my html:

```
        <form>
            <h2>Todo App</h2>
            <p>Add a new todo</p>
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter an activity......">
            <button type="button" id="add-button">Add Task</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Add the snippet so that. it will be helpful to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the required functionality to the `submit` event of the `form`:

```
var form = input.closest('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // important, otherwise the page will reload
  /* your code */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code / try has alot of issues.

1. You are missing some Elements in your HTML Code (e.g: an element with the id `todoList`). That causes your js code to fail because you cant call `appendChild()` on `undefined`.
2. You don't need a `<form>` element if you are just using client sided actions. If you want to wrap all you elements anyway just use a `<div>`
3. You are creating the `remove` element disregarding if the key was ENTER or not. Because of that the script fails due to **not** finding the proper elements.
4. No error but you have no functionality for your "add todo" button yet.
5. You have no element to show your `count`.
6. You should read more about the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

*Hope i could help you a bit.*

---

**Below you find a complete example to help you progress if you run into a corner**

```js
var button = document.getElementById('add-button');
var count = 0;
var input = document.getElementById('input');

updateCount();

input.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var key = event.keyCode;

  if (key === 13) {
    addTodo(input.value);
  }
});

button.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  addTodo(input.value);
});

function addTodo(newTodo) {
  var newItem = document.createElement('li');

  newItem.textContent = newTodo;
  document.getElementById('todoList').appendChild(newItem);
  count++;
  updateCount();

  var removeTask = document.createElement('img');

  removeTask.setAttribute('src', 'https://static.thenounproject.com/png/620343-200.png');
  removeTask.setAttribute('class', 'trash');
  removeTask.style.width = '15px';
  removeTask.style.height = '15px';
  removeTask.style.marginLeft = '10px';
  removeTask.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  removeTask.addEventListener('click', function() {
    newItem.parentNode.removeChild(newItem);
    count--;
    updateCount();    
  });
  newItem.appendChild(removeTask);
}

function updateCount() {
  var countElem = document.getElementById('count');
  
  countElem.textContent = count;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Todo App</h2>
  <p>Add a new todo</p>
  <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Enter an activity......">
  <button type="button" id="add-button">Add Task</button>
</div>
<p></p>
<h4> TODO LIST (<span id="count"></span>)</h4>
<ul id="todoList"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. I agree on the form thing, but other than that everything is ok I just haven't showed my entire html, but the needed elements are there.

Comment: Alright then next time it would be helpful to show your whole html, so we can test the actual code and not just have to guess it.

Answer (score 0):

`key === 13` need to be changed to `e.keyCode===13`
I have modified your code with some missing elements according to your code.

see working fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/Jkumar/oc5j9wsn/19/